# IAP Restore button

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm using a non-consumable IAP and trying to get the Restore button working properly.

I've noticed that when a user try's to buy something they've already purchased, an Apple alert comes up saying "You've already purchased this.  Would you like to get it again for free."

**So I was wondering how I could use that same exact receipt verification method/code for my Restore button?**

I can't seem to find the code for it.  I've looked in `paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` and other places?

Can you please help?  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
- (IBAction)purchaseRestore:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
    // Stack
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    NSLog(@"4 IBAction Purchase Restore Method");
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I can't tell if I'm doing this right, doubling up on some code, or adding unneeded code.

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"2 Payment Queue updatedTransactions - needs to verify logged in user: Purchasing Product From Store!");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                     isEqualToString:INAPP_PRODUCT_ID_3]) {
                    NSLog(@"3 Payment Queue updatedTransactions - Product Purchased From Store!");
                    //Not sure if I need this
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                              @"3 Payment Queue updatedTransactions - Seems to to this twice: Purchase is completed succesfully" message:nil delegate:
                                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alertView show];

                    [self saveTransactionReceipt:transaction];
                    NSLog(@"3 Payment Queue updatedTransactions - Save Transaction Receipt: Called after product purchased");
                    [self saveValue:transaction];
                    NSLog(@"3 Payment Queue updatedTransactions - Save Value: Called after product purchased");
                    [self showButtonThree];
                    NSLog(@"3 Payment Queue updatedTransactions: will Show button Three now");

                    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"purchasedThree"];
                    NSLog(@"updatedTransactions Yes for purchasedTeamThree: %hhd", [defaults boolForKey:@"purchasedThree"]);
                    [defaults synchronize];

                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    NSLog(@"3 Payment Queue finishTransaction: Run");
                }
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                    NSLog(@"Restored");
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                purchaseButton.enabled = YES;
                NSLog(@"2 Payment Queue updatedTransactions: Purchase failed ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually very useful to me too, since you made me realize that probably the app I currently have pending in the approval process of the AppStore will be rejected because I didn't implement a Restore button (I just added a label saying that pressing again the Buy button would restore previous purchases).

The correct way to do the restore process looks to implement a button calling this method:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

and after that, of course, restoring the app functionality restricted to paying users.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  Is that seriously the only line needed?  I've been trying a whole bunch of different stuff and can't get it working.  And where are you putting that line of code in, an IBAction when the Restore button gets purchased, or in the `updatedTransactions` part, or something different?  Thanks!

Comment: @Reez You're welcome! I added a Restore button linked to an IBAction calling `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` then in `-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` I added a switch case for `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`, very similar to the one I suppose you too have for `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`. I've looked to other answers here on StackOverflow too, and that seems all you need to do. It actually works in my tests, but my approval process is still pending...

Comment: Gotcha, I added my Restore button code above, with the addition now of `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`... can you let me know what you use for your `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`?  I understand sort of what your saying by it should be similar to `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`, but I can't figure out exactly what parts need to be there to get fired off.

Comment: Here's my `-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` method. I'll split it in this and another comment.
`{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockFeature]; // your method to unlock paid features
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;`

Comment: `case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restorePreviousPurchase]; // your method to unlock paid features
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
                
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
//                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
         
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: In my case, the custom methods unlockFeature (called in `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`) and restorePreviousPurchase (called in `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`) are almost identical. The only difference is that in the "restore" method I also alert the user of the successful restore.

Comment: So is the `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` all that needs to be written for apple to check if a user ID has a receipt that matches what their about to buy?

Comment: Because it seems to be firing off unlocking the purchase (for me) before it ever has a user log in to their account and check to see if they had already purchased that item (which I don't know what code tells Apple to check that).

Comment: @Reez When I press the restore button I'm asked to enter my password (if the time-window between purchases is expired); the restore was successful for my iap test account (which previously purchased the iap), and not successful for my regular account (which didn't previously purchase the iap, so nothing to restore). So I'd say yes, [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] is all that's needed to check if a user ID has a receipt that matches. In your SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored above I don't actually see any call to custom restoration method though

Comment: Cool, thanks for explaining what you're getting, do you mind adding your restoreButton code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59470/discussion-between-cdf1982-and-reez).